# DBIx::Class: How can I sort on multiple substrings of a column?

Tags: perl, sorting, dbix-class

I have a SQLite-database with table with a document number following this schema:

```
16-145-45
16-127-30
16-141-42
16-122-14
15-090-04
15-089-15
15-089-05
```

I'd like to sort the `ResultSet` on the first and last part of the number, like this. First, all documents starting with the highest two-digit prefix (16) sorted by the last 2 digits and then the same with the next block, and so on.

```
16-145-45
16-141-42
16-127-30
16-122-14
15-089-15
15-089-05
15-090-04
```

Is there a way to do this in `DBIx::Class` with some sort of custom `order_by` clause, or what would be the approach?

I have tried the following, which does not work, because the middle part of the number is also considered for sorting:

```perl
my @rs = $self->search(undef,
    {
        order_by => { -desc => 'me.number' }
    }
);
```

Comment: @Chankey Why did you remove the sql-tag. Isn't it relevant?

Comment: I do not think your question is SQL specific. It's more about `DBIx::Class` and sorting.

Comment: You should say what database engine you're working with. Unless you're using PostgreSQL the `split_part` function isn't available to you. If someone doesn't say either way, the usual assumption is that you're using MySQL. Please update your question and tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the database to sort the results, you have to use [literal SQL](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Abstract#Literal-SQL-and-value-type-operators).

Here's an example for Postgres (I added a space after the backslash to fix the syntax highlighting):

```
my @rs = $self->search(undef,
    {
        order_by => \ "split_part(number, '-', 1) || split_part(number, '-', 3) DESC",
    }
);
```

Or, by creating an output column with the [`+select` result set attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#select1):

```
my @rs = $self->search(undef,
    {
        '+select' => [
            { sort_key => \ "split_part(number, '-', 1) || split_part(number, '-', 3)" },
        ],
        '+as' => [ qw(sort_key) ],  # Make sort key accessible from DBIC.
        order_by => { -desc => 'sort_key' },
    }
);
```

Another approach is to retreive the whole unsorted result set, and sort it on the client side. DBIC doesn't have any specific features to help you with that, so simply use Perl's `sort` function.

Comment: That's a very, erm lumpy solution. Why not just use bare `DBI` if you're going to do that? The [documentation for `DBIx::Class::ResultSet`](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.082840/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#order_by) says, *"The old scalarref syntax (i.e. order_by => \'year DESC') is still supported, although you are strongly encouraged to use the hashref syntax as outlined above"*. I also strongly suggest that you use the hash ref syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract additional columns from the result set which are equal to the value of the function that you want to sort by. Then you can just put those columns in an `order_by` clause as normal

This assumes that your *document number* field is called `docnum`. It fetches all the columns from `Table` plus the two substrings of `docnum` called `docnum1` and `docnum3`

```
my $rs = $schema->resultset('Table')->search(undef,
    { 
        '+select' => [
            { substr => [ 'docnum', 1, 2 ], -as => 'docnum1' },
            { substr => [ 'docnum', -2 ],   -as => 'docnum3' },
        ],
        order_by => [ { -desc => 'docnum1' }, { -desc => 'docnum3' } ],
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the answer from @nwellnhof works like a charm, I just wanted to provide the corresponding syntax for SQLite, which does not know the `split_part()` function.

```
# SQL for filtering the doc number in SQLite

my @rs = $self->search(undef,
    {
        order_by => \ "SUBSTR(me.number, 1, 2) || SUBSTR(me.number, -2, 2) DESC"
    }
);
```